# Cast/Covert Substring Number to Specific Letter

Tags: sql, casting, substring, type-conversion

The following substring returns a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4:

```
SUBSTRING(GROUP_NAME, 1, 1)
```

My question: Is there a way to specify a letter for the number to convert to automatically?

1 and 3 should = "I"

2 and 4 should = "T"

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: You should add the relevant tag, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, nothing useful is ever possible automatically, you'll have to program it. This should do what you need:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Substring(Group_Name, 1, 1) IN ('1','3') THEN 'I' ELSE 'T' END as Lttr
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, You might also what to cast the substring as an int, and determine whether its odd/even etc

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Appreciate the help!